# Not exactly sure how I can further simplify these logic gates

Tags: math, logic, xor, gate

I'm not exactly sure how to simplify this further.

[image]

Comment: Is that "((not C) or (not (d xor P))) and (C or (d xor P))"?

Comment: It's ((not C) and (not (d xor P))) or (C and (d xor P))

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, which is probably better handled at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: How about "C = d xor P"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically your formula is true if C is 1 & d and p are different or if C is 0 & d and p are equal. So when `C` is true then `d ^ p` must be true, when `C` is false `d ^ p` must be false. So `C` and `~ (d ^ p)` must always be different. (`~` is NOT, `^` is XOR, `&` is AND)

So it should be equivalent to:

```
C ^ ( ~ (d ^ p))
```

which can even be written as

```
~ (C ^ (d ^ p))
```

Its truth table should be

```
C d p     d ^ p     ~(d ^ p)      C ^ (~(d ^ p))

0 0 0       0           1                 1
0 0 1       1           0                 0
0 1 0       1           0                 0
0 1 1       0           1                 1
1 0 0       0           1                 0
1 0 1       1           0                 1
1 1 0       1           0                 1
1 1 1       0           1                 0
```

Now compare it to the truth table of your expression:

```
C d p     d ^ p      ~ (d ^ p)    ~C     ~C & ~(d ^ p)    C & (d ^ p)     ~C & ~(d ^ p) | C & (d ^ p)

0 0 0       0             1        1          1               0                       1
0 0 1       1             0        1          0               0                       0
0 1 0       1             0        1          0               0                       0
0 1 1       0             1        1          1               0                       1
1 0 0       0             1        0          0               0                       0
1 0 1       1             0        0          0               1                       1
1 1 0       1             0        0          0               1                       1
1 1 1       0             1        0          0               0                       0
```